# model.fit_generator invalid loss and score

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am using keras for simple OCR. When calling `fit_generator` method, it shows invalid scores and loss.

I have updated from keras 2.0 to keras 2.1.3 but still have same issue.

Here is my generator function.

```
def generate_dataset(directory, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE):
    data = pd.read_csv(directory + 'data.csv')

    while 1:
        data.sample(frac=1)
        data_images = data['image']
        classes = np.array([CHARACTERS.index(i) for i in data['char']])
        classes = to_categorical(classes)

        for i in range(0, len(data_images), batch_size):
            y_train = classes[i:i+batch_size]
            x_train_filenames = data_images[i:i+batch_size].tolist()
            x_train = np.empty([len(x_train_filenames), 60, 60, 3], dtype=np.float32)

            for j in range(len(x_train_filenames)):
                im = Image.open(directory + x_train_filenames[j])
                arr = np.array(im).astype(np.float32) / 255
                x_train[j] = arr
                im.close()

            yield x_train, y_train
```

and method call

```
steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch=pd.read_csv(TRAIN_DIR + 'data.csv').shape[0] / BATCH_SIZE + 1
validation_steps = pd.read_csv(VALIDATION_DIR + 'data.csv').shape[0] / BATCH_SIZE + 1

model.fit_generator(
    generate_dataset(TRAIN_DIR),
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_data = generate_dataset(VALIDATION_DIR),
    validation_steps = validation_steps,
    verbose=1,
    epochs=5)
```

Here are outputs for first three epochs

> Epoch 1/5 783/782 [==============================] - 122s 156ms/step -
>   loss: 9.5539 - acc: 0.2319 - val_loss: 0.6028 - val_acc: 0.7958
>
> Epoch 2/5 783/782 [==============================] - 96s 122ms/step -
>   loss: 9.0007 - acc: 0.3991 - val_loss: 0.3196 - val_acc: 0.8865
>
> Epoch 3/5 578/782 [=====================>........] - ETA: 23s - loss:
>   8.9411 - acc: 0.4181

How You see, train loss is invalid.

I have run `evaluate_generator` method for train dataset, it works normally, shows real numbers, not 8.9 for loss.

> I am using Keras 2.1.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 with tensorflow backend

Comment: What are your losses?

Comment: after 5 epoch of training, validation loss calculated with evaluate_generator are 0.1647274633801071 for train set, 0.17947138977747581 for test set and 0.18689062354547717 for validation set. But fit_generator shows 8.9 for train set

Comment: Are `accuracies` the same?

Comment: 0.930193522906793 for validation, 0.9384887344199425 for train and 0.9331556082148499 for test

Comment: Could you show `evaluate_generator` code?

Comment: What do you mean the loss and scores are invalid?

Comment: `model.evaluate_generator(
    generate_dataset(TRAIN_DIR),
    steps=pd.read_csv(TRAIN_DIR + 'data.csv').shape[0] / BATCH_SIZE + 1)`

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I mean that fit_generator shows loss 8.9 while evaluate_generator shows 0.1

Comment: Both losses don't have to be equal, one is the mean over batches as the network is trained, and in evcaluate_generator the network is fixed.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes I understand, but after 5 epochs of training, in fit_generator training set loss still 8.9 while validation loss is 0.1. I understand that both losses dont have to be equal, but they dont have to be such different too.